# How to select options in multiple mat-select at initial loading by default?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to show by default checkbox selected on page load.
I tried with formcontrol but still getting issue.

TypeScript:

```js
public SelectbyDefault()
{
  this.servicedropdownsFA = [{id: "httpStatus/380/", value: 1},{id: "httpStatus/381", value: 2}]
}
```

HTML:

```html
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select placeholder="Select Error Category"  
    [formControl]="servicedropdownsControl" multiple>                 
        <mat-option *ngFor="let service of servicedropdownsFA" [value]="service"
        (click)="selectedFAdropdown($event,service,servicedropdownsControl)">
            {{service.id}}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: a multiple select "store" an array , so you can use some like `this.servicedropdownsControl.setValue([1,2])`, or if you're creating `this.servicedropdownControl=new FormControl([1,2])`, if your use in mat-option `[value]="service.value"` NOTE: Don't confused a formControl that store an array and a FormArray, a formControl can store anything, not only a number or and string. e.g. in ngb-datePicker store an object with day,month and year

Comment: see https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tvjyj2?file=src/app/select-overview-example.html. Take acoount I put ` <mat-option *ngFor="let service of servicedropdownsFA" [value]="service.value">` this **[value]="service.value"**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set it while initializing form group

[**For mat select** - Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-select-with-controlvalueaccessor-mhjtyn)

```
 this.poemForm = this.fb.group({
      servicedropdownsControl: [this.servicedropdownsFA[0], [Validators.required]],
    });
```

[**For normal select** - Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-select-dropdown-reactive-form-opnlhd)

```
this.form.controls['servicedropdownsControl'].setValue(this.servicedropdownsFA[0], {onlySelf: true});
```

[**For multiple matselect** - Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-select-with-controlvalueaccessor-fptvgt)

```
let defaultValues=this.servicedropdownsFA.slice(0,2);//or get your default set of objects
this.form = this.fb.group({
  servicedropdownsControl: [defaultValues, [Validators.required]],
});
```